# Ignore Tablename in ADODB recordset field name

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, powerpivot

I want to get data from an Excel Power Pivot model to an ADODB recordset. This works, but the field names of the recordset are preceded by the tablename: Tablename[Columnname] instead of just the columnname. How can I avoid this?

This is the code that works:

```
Public Sub ExportModelTable()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ModelTable
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim qry As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim f As ADODB.Field
    Dim col As ModelTableColumn
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    wb.Model.Initialize
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Model.ModelTables(2)

    qry = "EVALUATE " & "'" & tbl.Name & "'"
    Set cn = wb.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .Source = qry
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CursorType = 1
        .LockType = 1
        .Open
    End With
        
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        Blad2.Cells(1, i).Value = f.Name
        Debug.Print f.Name
        'prints Tablename[Columnname]
    Next f
    
    For Each col In tbl.ModelTableColumns
        Debug.Print col.Name
        'prints Columnname
    Next col
    
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could extract the field name using mid and instr functions.

In your case,

```
For Each f In rs.Fields
         i = i + 1
         fieldName = mid(f.Name,instr(f.name,"[")+1,instr(f.name,"]")-instr(f.name,"[")-1)
         Blad2.Cells(1, i).Value = fieldName
         Debug.Print fieldName
Next f
```